# Extract a max value from a query with joins

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have a query which gives me partially redundant rows. This is the query:

```
select r.id, u.reminder_id, r.name, r.remark, u.user_id
    from REMINDER_USERS u
    inner join REMINDER r 
        on r.id = u.reminder_id
    inner join DEVICE d 
        on d.id = (regexp_replace(r.origin_values, '[^0-9]', '')) 
    where r.name like '%Interne%'
```

There is a foreign keys constraint between `REMINDER` and `REMINDER_USERS`. So the rows in `REMINDER_USERS` are child data of `REMINDER`.

Here is an example of the result of the query:

| Line | ID | REMINDER_ID | NAME | REMARK | USER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1940 | 1940 | Interne_3324 | Interne Pruefung | 10 |
| 2 | 1940 | 1940 | Interne_3324 | Interne Pruefung | 11 |
| 3 | 1972 | 1972 | Interne_2379 | Interne Pruefung | 10 |
| 4 | 1972 | 1972 | Interne_2379 | Interne Pruefung | 11 |
| 5 | 1934 | 1934 | Interne_3324 | Interne Pruefung | 10 |
| 6 | 1934 | 1934 | Interne_3324 | Interne Pruefung | 11 |
| 7 | 3103 | 3103 | Interne_3324 | Interne Pruefung | 10 |
| 8 | 3103 | 3103 | Interne_3324 | Interne Pruefung | 11 |
| 9 | 4100 | 4100 | Interne_2379 | Interne Pruefung | 10 |
| 10 | 4100 | 4100 | Interne_2379 | Interne Pruefung | 11 |

What i want to do is to eliminate all rows but these with the maximum value for the `ID` or `REMINDER_ID`. In the example that would be just to keep rows 7 and 8 for the Reminder with the name "Interne_3324" and rows 9 and 10 for the Reminder with the name "Interne_2379".

I tried several subquery with `select (max)id` in the first join, but this did not work.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `dense_rank()` or `rank()` and some additional filtering:

```
select r.*
from (select r.id, u.reminder_id, r.name, r.remark, u.user_id,
             dense_rank() over (order by u.reminder_id desc) as seqnum
      from REMINDER_USERS u join
           REMINDER r 
           on r.id = u.reminder_id join
           DEVICE d 
           on d.id = (regexp_replace(r.origin_values, '[^0-9]', '')) 
      where r.name like '%Interne%' and
            r.name <> 'Interne_2379'
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If you actually want the most recent reminder *per user*, then use:

```
             dense_rank() over (partition by u.user_id order by u.reminder_id desc) as seqnum
```

Comment: Okay, with a small adaption I get the most recenct reminder per name:

`dense_rank() over (partition by r.name order by u.reminder_id desc) as seqnum`

But how can I now select all rows but these? These would be finally the rows, that I want do delete. I plan to do a `bulk select` on these rows in order to delete them.

Comment: Okay, i can answer that for myself: `seqnum > 1` seems to do it.